# Python Socket, how do i choose between s.send and conn.send?

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

```
def send_Button():
    try:
        myMsg = "ME: " + text.get()
        msg = text.get()
        conn.send(msg) ###
        textBox.insert(END, myMsg + "\n")
        textEntry.delete(0, END)
        textBox.yview_pickplace("end")
    except NameError:
        myMsg = "ME: " + text.get()
        msg = text.get()
        conn.send(msg) ###
        textBox.insert(END, myMsg + "\n")
        textEntry.delete(0, END)
        textBox.yview_pickplace("end")
```

This program uses the tkinter module with socket in python2.7. My program allows for you to either connect to a server to chat with or host a server for others to connect to you, but whenever I try and test it out then the lines with the '###' on always bring up an error and it doesn't work, the error which comes up is: "NameError: global name 'conn' is not defined" OR "error: [Errno 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied".

Any help please?

Comment: Where is conn defined?

Comment: What is the point of catching `NameError`, and then *retrying exactly the same code*?  The same error is guaranteed to happen again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are trying to get the program to act as a Client or as a Server just changing `s.send()` to `conn.send()` saddly it isn't that simple.

## Socket Initializzation

The socket have to be initialized before sending or receiving data.

For a client usually it's something like this.

```
send_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) # Create the socket
send_socket.connect((serverIp, serverPort))  # Connect to the server
send_socket.send(data)  # Send the data to the server
```

And like this for a Server:

```
listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) # Create the socket
listen_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", port)) # Set the socket to accept client from every interface on the port port
listen_socket.listen(1) # Put the server on listen on the port setted before
accept_socket, addr = self.listen_socket.accept() # when a client connect return the socket to talk with it
data = self.accept_socket.recv(buffer_size) # Receive data form the client of max size buffer_size
```

### Docs examples

From your question I guess that with `s.send()` and `conn.send()` you are talking about

[this example from the python 2.7 socket docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)

> Here are four minimal example programs using the TCP/IP protocol: a server that echoes all data that it receives back (servicing only one client), and a client using it. Note that a server must perform the sequence socket(), bind(), listen(), accept() (possibly repeating the accept() to service more than one client), while a client only needs the sequence socket(), connect(). Also note that the server does not sendall()/recv() on the socket it is listening on but on the new socket returned by accept().

#### Client

> ## Echo client program
>
> ```
> import socket
> HOST = 'daring.cwi.nl'    # The remote host
> PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server
> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
> s.connect((HOST, PORT))
> s.sendall('Hello, world')
> data = s.recv(1024)
> s.close()
> print 'Received', repr(data)
> ```

the client is pretty stright forward, it create the socket `s` and then after using `s.connect()` it just send data through it.

#### Server

The server one is where there there are both `s` and `conn`

> ## Echo server program
>
> ```
> import socket
> HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
> PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
> s.bind((HOST, PORT))
> s.listen(1)
> conn, addr = s.accept()
> print 'Connected by', addr
> while 1:
>     data = conn.recv(1024)
>     if not data: 
>         break
>     conn.sendall(data)
> conn.close()
> ```

in this one first of all we create a socket `s` on which the server will listen and then using `s.accept()` it will wait till a client connect to the server and then return  the `conn` which is the socket of the connected client.

So to receive or send data to the client you have to use `conn`.

#### Notes

As said in the documentation in these two example the server accept only one client. So if you want to deal with multiple clients you have to repeat the `accept` step and possibly generate a new Thread for each client so that other clients don't have to wait for each others.

Comment: I have previously established the sockets in two functions, if i press one button then the program asks for an input of the IP and port to connect too. If i press the other button then it reaches out to the second function and asks a port to host the server on. Both functions have the sockets established for example; client for func one and server for func two. I.m just trying to receive/send msgs with the send() and recv(), the prefixes (s, conn) depend on whether the program is on server mode or client, how do I create that dependency in code?
I'm sorry im hopeless at explaining :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't got that from your question ahahah, btw I think the easiest way is to pass the socket as an argument to the function and save pass it the right one. Or you might make a new variable where you save the correct prefix like `my_socket = s` or `my_socket = conn` depending on the case